# Updating Listview itemsource clears radiobutton in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have defined a listview and 2 buttons as follows.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvTest" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                              HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <RadioButton Padding="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"
                                         GroupName="L1" Content="{Binding Description}"
                                         ></RadioButton>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Amount}" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Padding="0,0,10,0"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Clicked="btnAdd_Clicked" Text="Add"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Clicked="btnRemove_Clicked" Text="Delete"/>
```

Following is the code in the codebehind class

```
public partial class Listview : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<CommonModel> temp = new ObservableCollection<CommonModel>();
    CommonModel model;
    public Listview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvTest.ItemsSource = temp;
    }

    void btnAdd_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        model = new CommonModel();
        model.Description = "Radio 1";
        model.Amount = 100;
        temp.Add(model);
    }

    void btnRemove_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        temp.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

When i run the application and click on add button i see the following output.
[image: Screen 1]

Now when i click on Delete button the listview becomes empty.
Up till this point everything is working fine.

Now when i click on Add button the listview does not show Radiobutton and shows only amount. Following is the screen shot

[image: Screen2]

Now when i again click on Add button i see radio button and amount both on 2nd row. Following is the screenshot

[image: Screen 3]

Can anyone guide me why does the radio button does not show up in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restore your code and repeat your operation. After deleting the RadioButton, I clicked the add button again, and the result was added normally. So I provide the code for your reference.

**This is my latest code**

Here is the cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<CommonModel> temp = new ObservableCollection<CommonModel>();
    CommonModel model;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvTest.ItemsSource = temp;
    }

    void btnAdd_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        model = new CommonModel();
        model.Description = temp.Count + "Radio";
        model.Amount = 100;
        temp.Add(model);
        lvTest.ItemsSource = temp;
    }

    void btnRemove_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        temp.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView x:Name="lvTest" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                          HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <RadioButton Padding="10,0,0,0" GroupName="L1" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"
                                      Content="{Binding Description}"
                                     ></RadioButton>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Amount}" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="End" Padding="0,0,10,0"> </Label>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Clicked="btnAdd_Clicked" Text="Add"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Clicked="btnRemove_Clicked" Text="Delete"/> 
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Wen, i have updated my post with screenshots.

Comment: It seems to only appear in ios, I tried to use CollectionView instead of ListView to successfully solve the problem.

Comment: If i use CollectionView i get NULL reference error on  temp.Add(model); line

Comment: You need to replace all ListViews with CollectionViews and delete ViewCells, and the rest do not change.

Comment: I have updated my code and it works normally.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?